# How to uncorrupt a minecraft world(Has Java error code)

Tags: java

I was using a lan server on my favorite world and when i saved and exited the world everything worked fine. Then later i tried to enter the world and it glitched out a bit at the load screen and when i got onto the world, it was VERY unresponsive, by that I mean that i would break a block and nothing would happen, the block just disappears, when i try to access chests it takes a good two minutes to see the contents. After a little while it crashes and i get this error code:

```
  Minecraft has crashed!      
  ----------------------      

Minecraft has stopped running because it encountered a problem; Exception in server tick loop

A full error report has been saved to C:\Users\SovietOnion\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\crash-reports\crash-2012-11-15_00.11.55-server.txt - Please include a copy of that file (Not this screen!) if you report this crash to anyone; without it, they will not be able to help fix the crash :(



--- BEGIN ERROR REPORT 1e5074f8 --------
Full report at:
C:\Users\SovietOnion\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\crash-reports\crash-2012-11-  15_00.11.55-server.txt
Please show that file to Mojang, NOT just this screen!

Generated 11/15/12 12:12 AM

-- System Details --
Details:
Minecraft Version: 1.4.4
Operating System: Windows 7 (amd64) version 6.1
Java Version: 1.7.0_05, Oracle Corporation
Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
Memory: 318267992 bytes (303 MB) / 534249472 bytes (509 MB) up to 954466304 bytes (910 MB)
JVM Flags: 2 total; -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
AABB Pool Size: 23258 (1302448 bytes; 1 MB) allocated, 23258 (1302448 bytes; 1 MB) used
Suspicious classes: No suspicious classes found.
IntCache: cache: 15, tcache: 0, allocated: 3, tallocated: 63
Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
Vec3 Pool Size: 149614 (8378384 bytes; 7 MB) allocated, 149614 (8378384 bytes; 7 MB) used
Player Count: 0 / 8; []
Type: Integrated Server (map_client.txt)
Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and both client + server brands are untouched.

java.lang.NullPointerException
at cf.b(SourceFile:103)
at cf.a(SourceFile:35)
at iv.b(SourceFile:437)
at gm.a(SourceFile:72)
at bdr.b(SourceFile:73)
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.r(SourceFile:769)
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.q(SourceFile:686)
at bdo.q(SourceFile:117)
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(SourceFile:620)
at fy.run(SourceFile:856)
--- END ERROR REPORT 8eb5620c ----------
```

When it says that the full error report is located at "" It says this:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// I'm sorry, Dave.

Time: 11/15/12 12:18 AM
Description: Exception in server tick loop

java.lang.NullPointerException
at cf.b(SourceFile:103)
at cf.a(SourceFile:35)
at iv.b(SourceFile:437)
at gm.a(SourceFile:72)
at bdr.b(SourceFile:73)
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.r(SourceFile:769)
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.q(SourceFile:686)
at bdo.q(SourceFile:117)
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(SourceFile:620)
at fy.run(SourceFile:856)


-- System Details --
Details:
Minecraft Version: 1.4.4
Operating System: Windows 7 (amd64) version 6.1
Java Version: 1.7.0_05, Oracle Corporation
Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
Memory: 190459000 bytes (181 MB) / 536018944 bytes (511 MB) up to 954466304 bytes (910 MB)
JVM Flags: 2 total; -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
AABB Pool Size: 23208 (1299648 bytes; 1 MB) allocated, 23208 (1299648 bytes; 1 MB) used
Suspicious classes: No suspicious classes found.
IntCache: cache: 15, tcache: 0, allocated: 3, tallocated: 63
Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
Vec3 Pool Size: 149633 (8379448 bytes; 7 MB) allocated, 149633 (8379448 bytes; 7 MB) used
Player Count: 0 / 8; []
Type: Integrated Server (map_client.txt)
Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and both client + server brands are untouched.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `NullPointerException` in an application that has been obfuscated (like this one clearly has), can only be debugged by the vendor / supplier.

I suggest that you submit a bug report .... and pray to your preferred deity.

You might also be able to get help on Minecraft forums.

But basically, this is not something we can help you with here ... because of the closed / obfuscated nature of the application you are using.

Comment: "to your preferred deity" You are crafted out of gold sir...